# How does a JSON Web Token verify users on authentication?

Tags: java, spring, jwt

How does a JSON Web Token verify a user on authentication? Does the JWT store user data?

If so, how can I get a list of users who have done authentication?

Comment: I think you have a general misconception about JWTs. a JWT contains all relevant information about ONE user, e.g. username, unique id, maybe some additional information (e.g. expiration time). It may be clear-text or encrypted, but in every case it should be signed. The idea oaf JWTs is that you do not store information on the server (or, at least, as few as possible, you typically need some server-side storage for update tokens).

Comment: @Turing85 you should format your comment and post it as an answer as it actually answers the question...

Comment: @LucasOliveira nah, too lazy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of token-based authentication, a *token* is a piece of data that identifies a user, working as a credential to perform authentication.

---

[JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) is a self *contained token* that contains three parts:

- Header
- Payload
- Signature

The payload contains a set of claims and you can use it to store any arbitrary data.

The integrity of the token can be checked by verifying the signature that is generated on server side with a private key, using both header and payload encoded as Base64. JWT allows you to perform *stateless authentication*, that is, you don't need to store anything on server side besides the key used to sign the token.

---

[`sub`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2) is the standard payload claim to store the principal who is the subject of the JWT (the user who the token was issued for):

> [**4.1.2.  "sub" (Subject) Claim**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2)
>
> The `sub` (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the
> subject of the JWT.  The claims in a JWT are normally statements
> about the subject.  The subject value MUST either be scoped to be
> locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique.
> The processing of this claim is generally application specific.  The
> `sub` value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI
> value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.